# How do I convert a user-generated Oracle EBS spreadsheet into a SQL-driven script?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I need to convert a manually-created spreadsheet into a SQL report. The report is generated via Oracle Forms (one of the BI Suite apps).

There's an inbox where many tickets come in to, identified by a "Request Number"

Each Request Number is a help desk ticket in the system. Here is a screenshot of that spreadsheet:

[image]

A full listing of columns(with descriptions) :

```
Request No. 
Modules
Submitted ( the request being submitted , a timestamp )
Supervisor ( the request being approved , by supervisor )
Average Supervisor Approval Duration
Responsibility
Average Resp. Approval Duration
Training (the request being approved for completing training)
Average Training Approval Duration - 
Configuration - depending on whether its PRISM or iProcurement
Average Config. Approval Duration
Approved
Total Overall Duration
Security 
Average Security  Approval Duration
SOD 
Avg SOD Approval Duration
```

So what I'm trying to do is to generate, some or all, of it using a SQL script.

One of my issues is that .. for a specific "Request Number" I'll often get redundant and conflicting data in the database.

Below is my query so far.

```
SELECT   hur.reg_request_id AS "Request No", 
     RESPONSIBILITY_NAME AS "Module", 
     to_char(hur.creation_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Submitted" ,  
     to_char(hur.last_update_date,    'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "Supervisor" ,     
     ROUND((hur.last_update_date - hur.creation_date), 3 ) || 
           ' days' AS "Avg Supervisor Appr Duration" ,          
     /* hura.creation_date AS "Responsibility" */, 
     NULL AS "Avg Resp Appr Duration", NULL AS "Training",     
     NULL AS "Avg Training Appr Duration" , 
     hur.LAST_UPDATE_DATE AS "Security", 
     NULL AS "Avg Security Appr Duration",     
     NULL AS "SOD", 
     NULL AS "Average SOD Approval Duration" , 
     NULL AS "Configuration",      
     NULL AS "Avg Config Appr Duration",       
     hurr.last_update_date AS "Approved", 
     ROUND( hurr.last_update_date - hur.creation_date, 2 )  
              AS  "Total Overall Duration",     
     NULL AS "Notes"           

     FROM HHS_UMX_REG_SERVICES hur     
        JOIN fnd_responsibility_vl frt 
          ON (hur.responsibility_id = frt.responsibility_id and
              hur.responsibility_application_id = frt.application_id)
    JOIN 
         hhs_umx_reg_requests hurr ON 
           (hurr.reg_request_id = hur.reg_request_id )

       /* JOIN hhs_umx_resp_activity  hura */
      left outer JOIN 
          hhs_umx_resp_activity  
          hura ON (hur.reg_request_id = hura.reg_request_id )--ADD ON 

      WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT  NULL  FROM hhs_umx_resp_activity hura
      WHERE hura.created_by = hur.created_by 
          AND
      hura.creation_date > hur.creation_date)
          AND hur.reg_request_id IN 
           ('263428', '263458', '263473', 
            '264717', '263402', '263404', 
            '262671', '263229', '263268')                        
      ORDER BY hur.reg_request_id ASC
```

Here are the schemas :

**HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY**
[image]

**HHS_UMX_REG_SERVICES**
[image]

**fnd_responsibility_vl**

[image]

**hhs_umx_reg_requests **

[image]

thanks

Comment: My original question prompted answers, which are helpful - however it was somewhat misunderstood because I wasn;t clear about what I need

Comment: Can you provide the SQL to create the oracle tables? I will have a play with it.

Comment: @Mihai , ok I will look for them, I'm on my phone now.

Comment: You're saying you are getting conflicting data for specific requests. What kind of conflicts do you get, and what other problems do you experience with your current query?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without sample tables (with only a few rows) reproducing the issue. I think your duplicate data comes from a wrong join. You could try to completely remove `hhs_umx_resp_activity` from the query (I see that you commented places where it is used). Then if it continues it has to be related to the join on `hhs_umx_reg_requests` (you might be able to join an additional column or replace this join by something else, an `outer apply` for example).

Comment: @SébastienSevrin - You're right, I will double-check the whole JOIN logic. thanks alot !!!

Comment: @Coffee glad I could help :) Do not hesitate to post the updated query, it might help other users.

Comment: Added the table schemas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a simple solution you can just create rows that add the columns together in an SQL command. Something like "INSERT INTO TABLE ('REQ_NO', 'MODULE') VALUES (A2, B2)" etc. Then you can just use the excel function that copies it again and again for each row.

Another simple solution is to save the spreadsheet as CSV (play around with the exact CSV format to see what suits you) and then you might be able to just import it into your SQL table and play around there.

There are of course other more advanced solutions like TommCatt pointed out.

Comment: Hi Mihai , I added some more info to this , thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I have done this many times using Perl. There are packages for reading spreadsheets so just write the script to generate the insert statements needed. Then just write it into a nice .SQL text file which can then be executed by SQL Developer or whatever IDE you're using. Or just execute it directly from the Perl script.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to diagnose without sample tables (with only a few rows) reproducing the issue.
I think your duplicate data comes from a wrong join.
You could try to completely remove `hhs_umx_resp_activity` from the query (I see that you commented places where it is used).
Then if it continues it has to be related to the join on `hhs_umx_reg_requests` (you might be able to join an additional column or replace this join by something else, an `outer apply` for example).

Comment: Hi Sebastien , I'll try what you said  - thanks alot !4

Comment: @Coffee Table schema will help, but do you have a few rows for us to be able to reproduce the issue?